# Laravel phpunit tests fails with PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 near "0": syntax error

Tags: laravel, sqlite, testing, phpunit

After a composer update in my Laravel project all my tests fails. My Laravel version is 9.24.0

I use PHPUnit tests in a Docker container on Alpine Linux image (`php:8.1-fpm-alpine`).

`pdo_sqlite` and `sqlite3` php modules are both enabled and loaded (`php -m` said).

When I run `docker-compose run --rm phpunit` I get this result for all my tests:

```
Domain\Customer\Tests\Address\AddressModelTest::myTestName
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000]:
General error: 1 near "0": syntax error (SQL: CREATE TABLE ...

/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:759
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:719
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:545
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.php:109
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Builder.php:394
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Builder.php:241
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php:338
/var/www/html/database/migrations/2021_11_17_154600_alter_table_modify_content_column_type.php:18
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php:482
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php:400
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php:409
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php:210
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/View/Components/Task.php:36
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php:740
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php:210
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php:175
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php:118
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Console/Migrations/MigrateCommand.php:87
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php:616
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Console/Migrations/MigrateCommand.php:99
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:36
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Util.php:41
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:93
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:37
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:651
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:139
/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:308
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:124
/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:998
/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:299
/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:171
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php:102
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php:194
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php:263
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Testing/PendingCommand.php:286
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Testing/PendingCommand.php:465
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/InteractsWithConsole.php:80
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/RefreshDatabase.php:47
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/RefreshDatabase.php:22
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestCase.php:123
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestCase.php:92
/var/www/html/tests/MultitenancyTestCase.php:34

Caused by
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 near "0": syntax error

/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:538
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:752
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:719
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:545
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.php:109
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Builder.php:394
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Builder.php:241
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php:338
/var/www/html/database/migrations/2021_11_17_154600_alter_table_modify_content_column_type.php:18
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php:482
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php:400
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php:409
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php:210
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/View/Components/Task.php:36
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php:740
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php:210
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php:175
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php:118
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Console/Migrations/MigrateCommand.php:87
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php:616
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Console/Migrations/MigrateCommand.php:99
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:36
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Util.php:41
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:93
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:37
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:651
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:139
/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:308
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:124
/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:998
/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:299
/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:171
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php:102
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php:194
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php:263
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Testing/PendingCommand.php:286
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Testing/PendingCommand.php:465
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/InteractsWithConsole.php:80
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/RefreshDatabase.php:47
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/RefreshDatabase.php:22
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestCase.php:123
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestCase.php:92
/var/www/html/tests/MultitenancyTestCase.php:34
```

**UPDATE:**

The content of `2021_11_17_154600_alter_table_modify_content_column_type.php` file is:

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('menu_contents', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->mediumText('content')->change();
        }); # this is the 18. line
```

I tried to downgrade `laravel/framework:9.3.0`, but itsn't helped.

Any idea how can I fix this?

Comment: Seems clear the problem is at `2021_11_17_154600_alter_table_modify_content_column_type.php:18`. Have you checked this?

Comment: Sure, it's a valid file. If I run migration in works fine. Only in phpunit gets error.

Comment: Including the full error text would also provide clues. It's cut off in your output, but I'd imagine the full string is in your logs. It should tell you what query was trying to be executed.

Comment: Actually, I think this is your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47196859/laravel-phpunit-failing-on-alter-table-using-sqlite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here for recent issue in doctrine/dbal https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/issues/5584 rolling back to 3.3.7 resolved my issues.